# RibbonComboBox has no selectionChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, ribbon

I have a combo box in my program and it works as it should

However I want this to be a part of my ribbon in my WPF application

I have created a 'ribbon combo box', however this does not seem to have a selection changed event, like the normal combo box does

Why is this?

If I cut and paste the code from my standard combo box into a ribbon group, the box is created however it is empty when I run the program

Also the only way I can run the program is by commenting out the code within my if statement (for what I want to happen based on the combo box selection)

Comment: What is actually being asked here? Does the OP want to implement a selection changed event on the ribbon combo box? Because it is pretty "easy" given that WPF is based on dependency properties.

Comment: I am new to WPF applications. Yes that is what I wanted to do. When you double click a combo box it creates a selection changed event, however when I looked in the event list for my ribbon combo box, I could not see any selection changed event so was wondering how you create one.

I have now used a textbox instead of combo box, to allow the user to simply type in a number but it would still be good to know the answer to my question if anybody knows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877), the `SelectionChanged` event can be found in the `RibbonGallery`

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox Style="{StaticResource SubPosition}" SelectionBoxWidth="20" IsEditable="True">
    <ribbon:RibbonGallery Name="rbngFontSizes" SelectedValue="11" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectionChanged="rbngFontSizes_SelectionChanged">
        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
</ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```