# How to use a RibbonGallery with a RibbonComboBox

Tags: wpf, ribbon, reactiveui

So I wanted to add a RibbonCombobox to my Ribbon in WPF. For some reason, RibbonCombobox does not have a selectionchanged event. I read that you should use a RibbonGallery for selection change event so I implemented this

```
 <RibbonComboBox   Label="Equations" x:Name="EquationListComboToolbar"  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <RibbonGallery x:Name="EquationListComboboxGallery" SelectedValue="{Binding  XPath=.}" />
                        </RibbonComboBox>
```

Behind the scene the binding is done like this.

```
  EquationListComboToolbar.DataContext = ViewModel.EquationNames;
                this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SelectedEquation, v => v.EquationListComboboxGallery.SelectedItem).DisposeWith(cleanup);
                Observable.FromEventPattern(EquationListComboboxGallery, nameof(EquationListComboboxGallery.SelectionChanged)).Subscribe(e => ViewModel.SelectEquation(EquationListComboboxGallery.SelectedItem?.ToString()));
```

At runtime I get the following error

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource." When the app initalizez. I know it's something about the Gallery but I can't figure out what is the problem and how can I achieve this.

As I was suggested, I already tried the answer that was suggested

```
 <RibbonComboBox   Label="Equations" x:Name="EquationListComboToolbar"  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <RibbonComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <RibbonGallery x:Name="EquationListComboboxGallery" SelectedValue="{Binding  XPath=.}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </RibbonComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </RibbonComboBox>
```

Doing this, will make by binding imposible

[image]

Comment: You have added a RibbonGallery as item.

Comment: @Clemens I tried to add it as an item template but then EquationListComboboxGallery it's no more available to bind behind.

Comment: @Clemens can you please reopen the question, you just posted a link to an answered question, which does not answer my question at all.

Comment: It does exactly tell you what you did wrong. Do not add a RibbonGallery  as item, or do not bind the ItemsSource property. If you want to know what you should actually do, rephrase the question and especially the title.

Comment: @Clemens no it does not, all the answers there have the same problem a missing parent . Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943134/ribboncombobox-has-no-selectionchanged-event RibbonGallery does not require a parent. If you are not willing to help, don;'t just close the question as duplicate. I'm been search for 3 hours on all the posts possible about this matter. It's not like I did not try everything I possible could.

Comment: Then edit the question title. The cause of the error message is obvious. What you actually want to know is something completely different.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what else to put in the title, feel free to edit it, as it looks like you know better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210245/discussion-between-ciucas-and-clemens).

Comment: From your very first example, remove the ItemsSource from the RibbonCombobox completely.

Comment: That will not show any elements in my combobox, why would I do that that? Just to have a working ribboncombobox with no items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, yes. The Microsoft ribbon library is lots of fun. Luckily I've been down this road before. Here's a working example of a `RibbonComboBox` from one of my applications, complete with `RibbonGallery`:

```
<RibbonComboBox DropDownHeight="400">
    <RibbonGallery MaxColumnCount="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItemProperty}">
        <RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSourceProperty}"/>
    </RibbonGallery>
</RibbonComboBox>
```

I'm not entirely sure this is the only way to do things, but I know this way works. Note that I set `ItemsSource` on the `RibbonGalleryCategory`, not the `RibbonComboBox` itself. It might be possible to use the `RibbonGallery` without a `RibbonGalleryCategory`, in which case you would set `ItemsSource` on `RibbonGallery`, but I've not tested this.

Note you also have the ability to add multiple galleries categories to a single `RibbonComboBox` like so:

```
<RibbonComboBox DropDownHeight="400">
    <RibbonGallery MaxColumnCount="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItemProperty}">
        <RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding MyFirstItemsSourceProperty}"/>
        <Separator/>
        <RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding MySecondItemsSourceProperty}"/>
    </RibbonGallery>
</RibbonComboBox>
```

The above lets you show multiple lists in the same drop down and allows the user to select a single item from any list. Functionality like this is probably why `RibbonGalleryCategory` exists in the first place.

Comment: Oh thank you, I will try it as soon as I get to that functionally again, hopefully tomorrow. But it looks like what I need.

Comment: Thank you it works, it is strange that you need this kind of a complex XAML to have a combobox  that have dynamic items and and SelectionChange event...

Comment: To display a default value for the selected item binding property, add `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on the `RibbonGallery` (as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43142542/3809520)